# align-items property not working in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to use CSS Grid to align items which will be part of a navbar.

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/nodpekar/82p0x4hw/5/

I don't know why the below code does not align the items in class `navbar-items` in center.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.navbar-items {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Projects</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Blog</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Resume</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work, though you've missed that a `p` has a default margin, and the height of the `navbar-items` is the same as the content, so no vertical centering can take place: https://jsfiddle.net/dpg9e6La/

Comment: you need to tell more via css https://jsfiddle.net/7yLftnao/ or https://jsfiddle.net/7yLftnao/1/

Comment: @G-Cyr My comment/fiddle explains it

Comment: @lgson to me it was horizontal centering about the arrow  the keyword stands in the question title :)

Comment: @G-Cyr Yeah, you might be right, where changing the default `stretch` to `center` fixed the `span`'s horizontal alignment

Comment: the keyword `span` stands in the question title :)

Comment: @G-Cyr True ... I wanted it to be the other :)

Comment: thank you @LGSon and G-Cyr your answers helped. I like the way LGson put the borders. Ity help me understand where I was going wrong.

Comment: @Nodnin That's the number one trick when things looks "odd"... add a border :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `justify-content: center`, use `justify-items: center`. That's it.

```css
#navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.navbar-items {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  justify-items: center; /* new */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.1/css/all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Projects</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Blog</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Resume</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you were using flexbox instead of grid, then your alignment code would have worked:

```css
#navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.navbar-items {
  display: flex; /* adjustment */
  flex-direction: column; /* new */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.1/css/all.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Projects</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Blog</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-items">
    <p>Resume</p>
    <span><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason for this difference is due to the difference in layout structures.

- In flexbox, `justify-content` applies directly to flex items.
- In grid, `justify-content` applies to grid columns ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571889/3597276)).
- In flexbox, there is no `justify-items` property ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276))
- In grid, `justify-items` applies to grid items ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571889/3597276))

Hence, to make your layout work, use `justify-items` in grid and `justify-content` in flex.