# CSS Grid: How to align columns to the right?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am in the process of learning CSS grid. Now I am struggling to align the grid's content.

```css
.grid-container {
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  justify-content: end;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: span 7 / span 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">My item</div>
</div>
```

Let's go through the rules.

On the container:

- `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr))`: As far as I understood, this creates 12 equal columns based on the space available.
- `justify-content: end`: Shouldn't this align the grid items so they are flush against the end (right side) of the grid container?

On the child:

- `grid-column: span 7 / span 7`: Sizes the element to take up seven fractions of space from the twelve fractions (columns) available.

Why is the grid item not aligned against the end of the container?

Comment: because you are using 1fr. There is nothing to align since you are telling the columns to take all the available space. Use a small pixel value to see the difference

Comment: ^ and even with this, your grid item won't align to the right because it span the first 7 columns and there are 5 more at the right

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571889/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `grid-column: span 7 / -1`. span 7 columns but start from the last one:

```css
.grid-container {
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  /* justify-content: end; will do nothing */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: span 7 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">My item</div>
</div>
```

Also not that `justify-content` doesn't align grid items like it does in Flexbox. it align the grid tracks and `justify-items` align grid items inside the tracks.

Comment: I am truly amazed! My mental model of grid was wrong. Your answer helped me a lot to understand it better.